# How to connect Android app to ESP32 via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino-ide, esp32

I am trying to send a Time of Flight sensor (VL53L0X) data, which is integer through ESP32 board via bluetooth to the android app, that I am developing in Android Studio, but I am not able to connect to the board for some reason. I am still kind of a noob with android development and micro controllers. I would really appreciate all the help that I can get.

When trying to connect to the board by running **bluetoothSocket.connect();**
I get this exception: **java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1**

I think the problem is with UUID, but I am not 100% sure.

Here is the android studio code:

```
package fi.jamk.tof;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean showingBtnText = false;
    private static TextView textViewStatus, textViewDistance, textViewPaired;

    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT = 0;

    private static BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private static BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private static BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("65a8c5ed-3a5b-4f53-8b59-26277adcb1de");
    static final UUID serviceUUID = UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");

    private final static String MAC = "30:AE:A4:1F:A0:2A";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatus);
        textViewDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDistance);
        textViewPaired = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPaired);

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            textViewStatus.setText("Bluetooth is not enabled, enabling bluetooth");
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        textViewPaired.setText("Paired devices:");
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devices){
            textViewPaired.append("\nDevice: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
        }

        try{
            bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
            bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException ex){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }




        final Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(showingBtnText == true){
                    btnScan.setText("Scan");
                    showingBtnText = false;
                    textViewStatus.setText("Scan complete");
                    int distance = getData();
                    textViewDistance.setText(distance);
                } else {
                    btnScan.setText("Stop Scanning");
                    showingBtnText = true;
                    textViewStatus.setText("Scanning...");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private int getData(){
        int distance;
        if (bluetoothSocket != null) {
            try {
                InputStream data = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                String dataToString = getStringFromInputStream(data);
                distance = Integer.parseInt(dataToString);
                return distance;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return  0;
            }

        } else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the Arduino IDE code:

```
/* This example shows how to get single-shot range
 measurements from the VL53L0X. The sensor can optionally be
 configured with different ranging profiles, as described in
 the VL53L0X API user manual, to get better performance for
 a certain application. This code is based on the four
 "SingleRanging" examples in the VL53L0X API.

 The range readings are in units of mm. */

#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>
#include <MedianFilter.h>

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic;
bool deviceConnected = false;
float txValue = 0;
const int readPin = 32; // Use GPIO number. See ESP32 board pinouts
const int LED = 2; // Could be different depending on the dev board. I used the DOIT ESP32 dev board.

//std::string rxValue; // Could also make this a global var to access it in loop()

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

//#define SERVICE_UUID           "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" // UART service UUID

#define SERVICE_UUID           "65a8c5ed-3a5b-4f53-8b59-26277adcb1de"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"

class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
    }
};

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();

      if (rxValue.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println("*********");
        Serial.print("Received Value: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++) {
          Serial.print(rxValue[i]);
        }

        Serial.println("*********");
      }
    }
};

VL53L0X sensor;

MedianFilter test(10, 0);

// Uncomment this line to use long range mode. This
// increases the sensitivity of the sensor and extends its
// potential range, but increases the likelihood of getting
// an inaccurate reading because of reflections from objects
// other than the intended target. It works best in dark
// conditions.

//#define LONG_RANGE


// Uncomment ONE of these two lines to get
// - higher speed at the cost of lower accuracy OR
// - higher accuracy at the cost of lower speed

//#define HIGH_SPEED
//#define HIGH_ACCURACY

int val;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();

    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  // Create the BLE Device
  BLEDevice::init("ESP32 UART Test"); // Give it a name

  // Create the BLE Server
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create the BLE Service
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  // Create a BLE Characteristic
  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                    );

  pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  // Start the service
  pService->start();

  // Start advertising
  pServer->getAdvertising()->start();
  Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");

  sensor.init();
  sensor.setTimeout(500);

#if defined LONG_RANGE
  // lower the return signal rate limit (default is 0.25 MCPS)
  sensor.setSignalRateLimit(0.1);
  // increase laser pulse periods (defaults are 14 and 10 PCLKs)
  sensor.setVcselPulsePeriod(VL53L0X::VcselPeriodPreRange, 18);
  sensor.setVcselPulsePeriod(VL53L0X::VcselPeriodFinalRange, 14);
#endif

#if defined HIGH_SPEED
  // reduce timing budget to 20 ms (default is about 33 ms)
  sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(20000);
#elif defined HIGH_ACCURACY
  // increase timing budget to 200 ms
  sensor.setMeasurementTimingBudget(200000);
#endif
}

void loop()
{
  if (deviceConnected){

    val = sensor.readRangeSingleMillimeters();

    test.in(val);
    val = test.out();

    pCharacteristic->setValue(val);
    pCharacteristic->notify();

    //Serial.print(val);
    if (sensor.timeoutOccurred()) { Serial.print(" TIMEOUT"); }

    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help forum***.  Your question as it stands is quite a bit too broad.  There are a lot of moving parts between your code and the hardware, and you need to narrow down where the problem is first.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Did you set the Bluetooth Permissions in the manifest.xml ?
If not, check this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

you might need the following entries:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>`

Comment: Yes, i have the Bluetooth Permissions in the manifest. Thanks

Comment: Your Arduino code setups a BLE server, but your Android code is making a Bluetooth Classic connection. That obviously won't work since that's two different technologies.